# Concatenation in php

Tags: php, symfony, concatenation

I have a trouble in a php code with symfony framework.
The problem is that I want to display the variable Cell new from the variable Cell old

```
$Cell old = BIZ_0050_C01_210_d2 

$Cell new = BIZ_0050_C01_210_2 (without d )
```

all example that I found concatinate two different variables like first name and last name

I did'nt find how to concatinate different position of the same variable , it is possible in microsoft excel but i did'nt find how to resolve it with a php code

thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Are you sure you have only one d in the string ,  y=you want to take cell new from the Cell old ??, or just want to check the old variable value is there in the new variable value ?? or just only want to remove some particular character from a string ??

Comment: How is it in any way related to a framework?! Pick up some "PHP for beginners" and read the damned thing, before you start using any framework.

Comment: so replace the d from the old one, why concatenate??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use substr (http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function to have a part of the original string:

```
$oldCell = 'BIZ_0050_C01_210_d2';
$newCell = substr ( $oldCell , 0, strlen($oldCell) - 2 ) . $oldCell[strlen($oldCell) - 1];

echo $newCell;
```

Or:

```
$oldCell = 'BIZ_0050_C01_210_d2';
$newCell = substr ( $oldCell , 0, strlen($oldCell) - 2 ) . substr($oldCell, strlen($oldCell) - 1, 1);

echo $newCell;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful.

```
$Cellold = "BIZ_0050_C01_210_d2";
$ModifiedCell = substr($Cellold,0,-2);
echo $ModifiedCell;
$CellNew = $ModifiedCell . substr($Cellold,-1);
echo "<br>". $CellNew;
```